# How to create TextView that will act as a link

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I have a `Textview` with location:

eg. "Mountain View, CA"

What I want to achieve is to create this text to act like a Link - color,underline, focusability etc.

This link doesn't need to direct anywhere - surrounding view has attached onClick listener that fires google maps intent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
  TextView location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
  location.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
  Spannable spans = (Spannable) location.getText();
  ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View widget)
     {
        //put whatever you like here, below is an example
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Location clicked");
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();            
        dialog.show();
     }
  };
  spans.setSpan(clickSpan, 0, spans.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Your answer is working fine. But it shows whole text as link. how to make only link part should be clickable and not whole text.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer On the last line, change 0, spans.length() to be the range of the string that you want clickable.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

there is a example in ApiDemos which can solve your problem. Check out `com.example.android.apis.text.Link` class, it may help. Following is part of the code:

```
TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
t3.setText(
        Html.fromHtml(
            "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
            "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
            "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
t3.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

if you are not getting click callback

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Spannable` class with `mTextView.scollTo()` to create internal link